# Generate a PHP file in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

How can i create a PHP script that will generate PHP Files, it would be like a form or something. I am new to this things. Please help. I want it to generate a file in this format:

```
<?php
$infolink = 'http://minecraft.net';
$downloadlink = '***';
$ttext = 'Minecraft';
$ctext = 'Minecraft is a game about breaking and placing blocks. At first, people built structures to protect against nocturnal monsters, but as the game grew players worked together to create wonderful, imaginative things.';
$text = '
Minecraft is a game about breaking and placing blocks. At first, people built structures to protect against nocturnal monsters, but as the game grew players worked together to create wonderful, imaginative things.
It can also be about adventuring with friends or watching the sun rise over a blocky ocean. It’s pretty. Brave players battle terrible things in The Nether, which is more scary than pretty. You can also visit a land of mushrooms if it sounds more like your cup of tea.';
$video = 'XAj1acQ_CE4';
$background = 'https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/minecraft__140227211000.jpg';
?>
```

Comment: a php file is just another text file.

Comment: the strings get messed up

Comment: a form in one file and i used the default write method, i will try again

Comment: i will use a batch file to generate that file and i will use php to upload it

Comment: I think all you need is to revisit your file creation code and see where the text actually gets messed up, try something like [this](https://gyazo.com/cf197f14617e3cf34660dd69b056e892) for debugging purposes.

Comment: Completely off-topic: you don't need to crack minecraft to play offline single player, and servers won't allow a un-authed account to join. I hope this isn't an attempt at a password stealer.

Comment: no it is not, it is a website for cracks for games.

Comment: http://mihailcdn.esy.es/game.php?game=minecraft

Comment: NOTE: this is the testing site.

Comment: This is a really dumb way of using PHP - such a thing would typically be database driven. Creating a PHP file for every separate page on the site is silly. Also, you suck for serving cracked versions of indie games.

Comment: do you have a better idea for a website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PHP file is simply a text file.

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "<?php your PHP codes\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "more php codes\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "?>";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

I answered for what you've asked, however it seems like your approach is completely wrong !